# How does NLog interconnect class library and application?

Tags: c#, nlog, class-library

I have two C# projects (.NET Framework): class library and application which references the library.

I installed NLog as NuGet package to the class library where I use it for logging in the simplest possible configuration below. I have done no NLog configuration in the class library, I just use it:

```
public class MyAwesomeClass {
    ...    
    private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    ...
    public void MyMethod() {
        Log.Info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

In the application I reference both the class library and NLog library and again I use the simplest possible NLog configuration with no external XML file:

```
var consoleTarget = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(consoleTarget, NLog.LogLevel.Trace);
```

To my surprise, the application shows the log messages from the class library! How is this automatic interconnection implemented? What if I wanted to separate application and class library logging systems from each other?

Comment: Looks like [NLog uses the call stack to identify the caller](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/725632fc44b8011d173466899d245cc5c4d44c57/src/NLog/LogFactory-T.cs#L65-L73)

Comment: _"What if I wanted to separate application and class library logging systems from each other?"_ - what do you actually mean by that? Do you mean "what if I use Serilog in the app and NLog in the lib" or "what if want to log app to file, but lib to another"? Does it make sense?

Comment: If you mean, you don't want to see the lib's logs, you probably need to configure the namespace to a loglevel higher than the one that's active or even "None".

Comment: Nlog works with a bunch of static loggers/configuration. The LogManager is a static class that manages loggers throughout the entire application. When you use the same reference in two projects within the same application, they don't get their own "copies", the library is loaded once and shared between them. Static variables for example will have the same value whether referenced from project A or project B

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Oh yes, the static configuration of NLog resides in NLog's class library, not in my application nor my class library. That's the way how it works. Now I understand. Thank you.